# Border Radius Scroll Bar

Tags: overflow, css

I have two scroll bars and I've set a border radius for it with

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 17px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
   border-radius: 10px;
   border-top-left-radius: 0;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   border-top-left-radius: 0;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

I have assigned the Div's each unique ID's and a class for both: #Scroll1 & #Scroll2 & .Overflow

My issue is that the overflow is for scrolling through my table of data but both tables are in one big div and I wanted to match the border radius's to the main div.

here is an example:

[image]

I will position it better later but what I want is the bottom scroll bar to abandon its 
`border-top-right-radius` and the top scroll bar to drop the `border-bottom-right-radius`

Any help will be kindly appreciated.

here should be a friendly JSfiddle with the same issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/z98Kq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the top scrollbar has the `id` `#Scroll1` and the bottom `#Scroll2`, simply use:

```
#Scroll1{
   border-bottom-right-radius:0;
}
#Scroll2{
   border-top-right-radius:0;
}
```

If the bars dont have `id` attributes like this- you can use `nth-of-type` or `nth-child` (or their `first-` and `last-` derivations) to target the first (top) and last (bottom) scrollbars.

Given your fiddle provided [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/z98Kq/), you should use:

```
#canceltable::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb,#canceltable::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
   border-bottom-right-radius:0;
}
#Deletetable::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb,#Deletetable::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
   border-top-right-radius:0;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z98Kq/2/)

Comment: That example doesn't work the Id's are for the div's, not specifically the scroll bar

Comment: @ByronMcGrath - can you provide some HTML or a jsfiddle?

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! It was a little bit incorrect but I added the small change 
`#CancelTable ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb, #CancelTable ::-webkit-scrollbar-track 
{
    border-bottom-right-radius:0;
}
#Deletetable ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb, #Deletetable ::-webkit-scrollbar-track 
{
    border-top-right-radius:0;
}`

They needed spaces after each ID otherwise it bugged, not sure why it did it but its fine now thanks :)